# $\int_Z z^2 x^2 = \int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 z^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)^2 \,\,dr \,d\theta \, dz$

Tags: real-analysis, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

$Z = \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | -1 < z < 1, \,\ x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$

Calculate $\int_Z z^2x^2$.

---

My approach:

Polar coordinates: $x = r \sin(\theta),\,\,y = r \cos(\theta)$. Then:

$\int_Z z^2x^2 = $

$\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 z^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)^2 \,\,dr \,d\theta \, dz = $

$4 \int_{0}^1 \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1 z^2 r^2 \sin(\theta)^2 \,\,dr \,d\theta \, dz = $

$4 \int_{0}^1 z^2 \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1 r^2 \sin(\theta)^2 \,\,dr \,d\theta \, dz = $

$4 \int_{0}^1 z^2 (\int_0^{\pi} \sin(\theta)^2 \,d\theta)(\int_0^1 r^2 \,\,dr) \, dz = $

$\frac{4}{3} \int_{0}^1 z^2 (\int_0^{\pi} \sin(\theta)^2 \,d\theta) \, dz = $

$\frac{4}{3} \int_{0}^1 z^2 \frac{\pi}{2} \, dz = $

$\frac{2}{3} \pi \int_{0}^1 z^2 \, dz = $

$\frac{2}{9} \pi$

---

This is the wrong result though and I cannot find my mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the factor $r$. After the first equality, you should have$$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1r^{\color{red}3}\sin^2(\theta)z^2\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm dz=\frac\pi6.$$

---

As a side note, when we use cylindrical coordinates it is much more common to do $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Comment: Why? I substituted $x=r \sin(\theta)$, so $z^2x^2$ becomes $z^2 r^2 \sin^2(\theta)$?

Comment: Yes. But when you compute an integral and you decide to use cylindrical coordinates, you always have to multiply everything by the volume element, which is is $r$. That is, if the original function was $f(x,y,z)$, then that you have to integrate is $f(r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,z)r$.